# N1QL based query in couchbase of nested nested objects

Tags: java, spring-boot, couchbase

I'm working on a professional social network application using couchbase server 4.1 with spring data couchbase 2.2.4 in a spring boot application using java 1.8.
I want to replace the next stream which searches a LikeEntity with specific company in the database by a N1QL based query which searches a user with the same previous likeEntity unnested:

## Here is the service containing the stream to replace by the query:

```
@Service
class CompanyServiceImpl implements CompanyService{

    @Override
    public void addCompanyToLike(UserEntity user, Company company){
          int incrementValue=1;
          LikeEntity existingLike=user.getLikeEntities()
                                      .stream()
                                      .filter(le->le.getCompany().getName().equals(company.getName()))
                                      .findFirst();
          //rest of process
    }
 }
```

## Here is the different java beans you will need to look at:

### UserEntity class:

```
@Document
@ViewIndexed(designDoc = "user")
class UserEntity implements Serializable{
    @Field private String id;
    @Reference
    private List<LikeEntity> likeEntities=new ArrayList<LikeEntity>();

    //Other attributes plus getters and setters:
}
```

### LikeEntity class:

```
@Document
class LikeEntity implements serializable{

    @Reference
    private Company company;

    @Reference
    private Job job;

    // other attributes plus getters and setters
}
```

### As you see above, the LikeEntity class may contain any object liked by the user, it can be a company, a job or another object. Also the LikeEntity is stored only inside a user document as element of user's list of likes and not independately in the database.It's my choice of modelization because the LikeEntity won't by used in other java beans of my application

### Company:

```
@Document
@ViewIndexed(designDoc = "company")
class Company implements Serializable{
  @Field private String id;
  @Field private String name;
  //Other attributes plus getters and setters 
}
```

### N.B: I've tried the next query inside UserRepository but it didn't work:

### UserRepository:

```
@Repository
@N1qlPrimaryIndexed
@N1qlSecondaryIndexed(indexName = "user")
public interface UserRepository extends CouchbaseRepository<UserEntity, String> {
    @Query("SELECT b.*, likeEntity FROM #{#n1ql.bucket} AS b UNNEST b.likeEntities AS likeEntity WHERE b.id=$1 AND likeEntity.company.name=$2")
    UserEntity findByLikedCompanyName(String idUser
    , String companyName);
}
```

I'm looking for your answers, and thank you so much in advance.